# unexpected token r in JSON at position 1 While trying to parse simple JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse this simple JSON,
but its giving me an error:

```
let myjson = "{rahul: 'kumar', parul: 'sinha'}"
let result = JSON.parse(myjson)
console.log(result)
```

but it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse
```

Comment: keys and string values need to be wrapped in double quotes

Comment: That's not a valid JSON document. There are lots of JSON validators you can use to test whether your document is valid. Hint: `{foo: 1}` is JavaScript, `{"foo": 1}` is JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't understand Single quotes (')

so use double quotes instead.

```
let myjson = '{"rahul": "kumar", "parul": "sinha"}'
let result = JSON.parse(myjson)
console.log(result)
```

Learn more [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)